# Cannot validate a file with jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

Below is my JSP page,

```
<input name="txtemailid" type="text" id="txtemailid" placeholder="Email Id">
<input name="txtusername" type="text" id="txtusername" placeholder="User Name">
<input name="txtpassword" type="password" id="txtpassword" placeholder="Password">
<input name="txtcpassword" type="password" id="txtcpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
```

My jquery validating script is as follows,

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#frmCustomer').validate({
            rules : {
                txtemailid : {
                    required : true,
                    email : true
                },
                txtusername : {
                    required : true
                },
                txtpassword : {
                    required : true
                },
                txtcpassword : {
                    required : true,
                    equalTo : "#txtpassword"
                }
            },
            messages : {
                txtemailid : {
                    required : 'Please Enter Email Id.',
                    email : 'Please Enter valid Email Id.'
                },
                txtusername : {
                    required : 'Please Enter User Name.'
                },
                txtpassword : {
                    required : 'Please Enter Password.'
                },
                txtcpassword : {
                    required : 'Please Enter Confirm Password.',
                    equalTo : 'Passwords do not match.'
                }
            },
            errorPlacement : function(label, element) {
                $('<span class="arrow"></span>').insertBefore(element);
                $('<span class="error"></span>').insertBefore(element).append(label);
            },
        });         
    });
```

The problem is that, the error message `Invalid email` and `password does not match` are displayed before the user has typed anything in the field. I'm opening the JSP page in a pop up box. Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `#frmCustomer`? It's not in your HTML code.

Comment: Do you use the jQuery validate plugin?

Comment: have you tried to remove the Placeholder ?
If the validation is not called on form submit then the validation may take care about the placeholder which is not valid according to the rules (Email Id instead of an email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have validated it directly on doc ready, instead you can use `submit and keydown` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frmCustomer').on('submit keydown', function(){
         $(this).validate({
                     rules : {
                           ........
                     },
                     messages : {
                           ........
                     },
                     errorPlacement : function(label, element) {
                        ..........
                    } //<----here you have a ',' which is not acceptable in ie
         });
    });
});
```

You can apply multiple events on your element using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: Hey Jai I tried your code and the validations worked perfectly but the problem is that when I hit the submit button and even if the validations are incorrect then the  errors are displayed but the form is submited.

Comment: Can you produce it in the fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/fmDDq/ sry I dont know how to use the fiddle properly so I have displayed the javascript and html in a single file

Comment: not able to produce the case its working fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmDDq/1/